# Web Fonts CORS Error, but I set headers

Tags: apache, cors, font-face

I am trying to load web fonts from a CDN, but am getting a Cross Origin Request error. I have set the following headers in my httpd conf file:

```
Header Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: my-cdn-domain
```

and

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

and I see the Access-Control header in the console, but the fonts still do not load.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this had to do with us moving the site over to https. When we moved the site, we didn't update the origins in the cdn to be https also and that was causing the source to actually be our non-https server!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Header Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: my-cdn-domain
> ```

Your CDN domain has to give permission to your HTML domain, not the other way around.

Comment: According to MaxCDN in this article: https://www.maxcdn.com/one/tutorial/how-to-use-cdn-with-webfonts/, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @hgolov — That article doesn't express it very clearly, but it agrees with this answer. If you scroll down to the section "​I have added the code but, issue persists. Why?" you will see that it asks you to test that the header is added to the URL for the font file, not the URL for the HTML document.

Comment: thanks - I followed the directions for curl and got a 403 response for the font from the cdn. Now what?

Comment: Figure out why the server is forbidding access entirely (or continue to debug using the Net tab in the browser's developer tools)

Comment: Thanks for your help Quentin!